# I can't pass information from my controller to views

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, scope

I tried to var_dump my foreach loop howerver it returns NULL. My database is not empty and I've been declaring the correct variables but still it gives me an error which says

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/v_home.php

Line Number: 16
```

I have 3 controlles (c_home.php, c_verifylogin.php and c_login.php)

-> c_login.php loads the view for my log-in

-> c_verifylogin.php is where the validation and authentication process is done and tries to match the data from the database.

-> c_home is the controller where it will load the views for the homepage, this is also where i created a method for my studentinfo to display its fullname.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class C_home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_login','',TRUE);
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    }

    function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['studentid'] = $session_data['studentid'];
            $this->load->view('v_home', this->$data);
        } else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function studentinfo() {
       $this->data['query'] = $this->m_login->getStudentInfo(); 
       $this->load->view('v_home', $data);
    }

    function logout() {
         //remove all session data
         $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
         $this->session->sess_destroy();
         redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
     }

}
```

This is the view where the c_home.php will pass the information

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $studentid; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="c_home/logout">Logout</a>

 <h4>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</h4>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if (var_dump($query)){?>

     <?php foreach($query as $row){?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row->firstname;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
     <?php }?>
   </table>


 </body>
</html>
```

and then this is my model where all the queries are done:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_login extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function login($studentid, $password) 
    {
        //create query to connect user login database
        $this->db->select('studentid, password');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('studentid', $studentid);
        $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        //get query and processing
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
            return $query->result(); //if data is true
        } else {
            return false; //if data is wrong
        }
    }

   function getStudentInfo()
{
      $this->db->select('firstname,middlename,lastname');
      $this->db->from('studentinfo');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result_array();
}

}
```

I'm confused why it won't show any retrieved data from my views. I have already declared $query, is this the result of having too many controllers? Please help! New to PHP and CodeIgniter.

Comment: This is not a database question related.

Comment: @greg sorry it was one of the suggested tags, guess i clicked it accidentally

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change something in `C_home`, in your `studentinfo()` function, when you're returning your view you need to change `$data` to `$this->data`.

Comment: query is still undefined :'(

Comment: Actually, in your `studentinfo()` function `$this->data['query'] = $this->m_login->getStudentInfo(); $this->load->view('v_home', $data);` to `var_dump($this->m_login->getStudentInfo())` and see what it says.

Comment: I discovered something, when I var_dump using this url  `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_home/` it won't show the array `array(10104)` but when i specify the url with the function `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_home/studentinfo` it will display `array(10104)` is it something?

Comment: Yes, because you're loading the same view (`v_home`) in 2 places, `index()` and `studentinfo()`, but you're not passing the same data in each function. Because in your `index()` function you dont have any data for your `query` variable it doesn't load properly and causes error.

Answer (score 0):

Your both index and studentinfo fuction calling same view.But I think its not your purpose.You should have two different view. the problem is

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_home/ //this link will produce that error
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_home/studentinfo  //this link will not produce the same error.
```

here is solution you can remove that error but I am not sure what you exatly want.

```
function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['studentid'] = $session_data['studentid'];
        $data['query']=array();
        //add this line there.your error will gone.
        //rememeber it will not display current student's first name and last name

        //or you can use this 
        //$this->data['query'] = $this->m_login->getStudentInfo(); 
        //remember your model returns all students info not current student.
        //so it will show all students info

        //if you want only current student's info u need
        //$data['query'] =something that will return only current loged user's info


        $this->load->view('v_home', this->$data);
        //here you calling v_homve view but not passing $query;
    } else {
    //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

The main problem was at your `Index` function you was not passing `$query` at your view.
You should know how to pass variable from controller and accept it inside view